# regex re.findall to to find the substrings with space on both sides

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am trying to use re.findall on my text column to find either of the following with spaces at both the sides, since thats the only important. I am using following script

```
url = '#MnA deals for 2015 across all #oilandgas sectors were lower than WAR WARduring the CFO Great CIO Recession' 

regex=re.findall(r'WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder+',url)  
print regex 
['WAR', 'WAR', 'CFO', 'CIO']
```

Instead of this I wanted only

```
['WAR', 'CFO', 'CIO']
```

Since 2nd time its not just WAR, its WARduring and I don't want that

And also what will be the operator to get everything I want to see in front of subscript, like

```
['WAR', 'WARduring','CFO', 'CIO']
```

Appreciate every help

Comment: Is `+` in `Founder+` a literal `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b(?:WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder+)(?=\s|$)', url)
['WAR', 'CFO', 'CIO']
```

`(?=\s|$)` will assert presence of a whitespace or line end after your keywords.

For 2nd task use this regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b((?:WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder+)\w*)', url)
['WAR', 'WARduring', 'CFO', 'CIO']
```

Here `\w*` after your keywords will match 0 or more word characters.

Answer (score 2):

Using word boundary [[Know more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) ] in your regex will solve your problem

Regex

```
\b(?:WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder+)\b
```

Code

```
url = '#MnA deals for 2015 across all #oilandgas sectors were lower than WAR WARduring the CFO Great CIO Recession' 

regex=re.findall(r'\b(WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder+)\b',url)  
print regex 
['WAR', 'CFO', 'CIO']
```

Answer (score 2):

method 1: wrongly detects theWAR as WAR

Another way of doing it: use \b to delimit word only

```
regex=re.findall(r'\b(WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder)\b',url)


url = '#MnA deals for 2015 across all #oilandgas theWAR sectors were lower than WAR WARduring the CFO Great CIO'

regex=re.findall(r'(WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder+)(?=\s|$)', url)  # bug with start of word
print regex
regex=re.findall(r'\b(WAR|CIO|CISO|CTO|C-Suite|CMO|CFO|Founder)\b',url)
print regex
['WAR', 'WAR', 'CFO', 'CIO']
['WAR', 'CFO', 'CIO']
```